# Преобразование списков Python

Tags: python, numpy, список

Есть список с элементами от 0 до 1024. Как создать второй список элементы которого будут вычислены из элементов первого первого?
То что у меня получилось, в меру понимания, но не работает(

```
for x in DataX:
    if x <= 1024
        res = 1024 - x
    else: res = -(1024-x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте *списковое включение* и *тернарный if*, если `DataX` это список питона:

```py
res = [1024 - x if x <= 1024 else -(1024 - x) for x in DataX]
```

А если `DataX` это `numpy.array`, то используйте `np.where`:

```py
res = np.where(DataX <= 1024, 1024 - DataX, -(1024 - DataX))
```